# Viewing javascript source maps visually

Tags: javascript

I remember finding a source map viewer somewhere one time, which showed you the source and the source-map side by side (i think also with the compiled code), and let you scroll your mouse around to see different parts of the source map.

I can't for the life of me find it now, but I really want to use it to verify the integrity of my source map (can't tell if bug in the map or in chrome).

Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Also asked on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28507732/588306).

Answer (score 2):

Oh, YES I found it! From the guy who gave us webpack:

http://sokra.github.io/source-map-visualization/

Comment: Have a large upvote, I love this tool! And mark this answer as accepted since it's exactly you (and probably others as well) are looking for